# Charge $q$ near Current-Carrying Wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

A charge $q$ nears a current-carrying wire. How does $q$ move? Specifically, what is $\vec{r}(t)$ for $q$?
[image]

I've found the direction of some of the forces acting on the charge $q$:

[image]
Using the Biot-Savart Law and Coulumb's Law, I can also find the Magnitude of the Magnetic and Electric Fields. I've used a suitable Amperian Loop for Ampere's Law, and computed the Magnetic Field to be as follows:

$$
d \vec{B}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4 \pi} \frac{i d \vec{s} \times \vec{r}}{r^{3}} \\
d B=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4 \pi} \frac{i d s(r \sin \theta)}{r^{3}} \\
B=\frac{\mu_{0} i}{4 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d s(r \sin \theta)}{r^{3}}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
B=\frac{\mu_{0} i}{4 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d s(r \sin \theta)}{r^{3}} &=\frac{\mu_{0} i}{4 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{R d s}{\left(s^{2}+R^{2}\right)^{3 / 2}} \\
&=\frac{\mu_{0} i}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{R d s}{\left(s^{2}+R^{2}\right)^{3 / 2}} \\
=& \frac{\mu_{0} i R}{2 \pi}\left[\frac{s}{R^{2}\left(s^{2}+R^{2}\right)^{12}}\right]_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{\mu_{0} i}{2 \pi R}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Using Gauss' Law and a Cylinder as a Gaussian Surface, we have

$$
E(R)=\frac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_{0} R}
$$

And by the Lorentz Force formula, I have $\vec{F}=q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}$. Nevertheless, I'm still struggling to understand how the charge $q$ would move to these Electric and Magnetic Fields. Please advise.

Comment: You haven’t computed the wire’s magnetic field. The charge doesn’t feel its own electric field.

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks. I've added my computation of the Wire's Magnetic Field, which I found to be $\frac{{\mu}_{0}I}{2\pi R}$

Comment: Your first two equations have different powers of $r$ in the denominator and for some reason change notation from $\vec L$ to $\vec s$.

Comment: You need to compute the magnetic field as a vector.

Comment: What is $\lambda$? Wires aren’t charged. They have stationary protons and moving electrons. The net charge is zero.

Comment: @G.Smith Got it. I'm fixing my mistakes.

Comment: $R$ looks like a constant but it isn’t. I suggest calling it $\rho$, the usual notation for the radial coordinate in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Once you have the force, write $\vec F=m\vec a$ in cylindrical coordinates and try to solve the differential equations.

Comment: You say “A charge $q$ nears a current-carrying wire” but in your diagram it is initially moving parallel to the wire, so it is not initially “nearing” the wire. Are you trying to solve for a particular initial condition, or for the general case?

Comment: I don’t remember whether the trajectory has a nice analytic solution, but my guess is that probably does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final expression for B is correct and could have been found using  Ampere's law.  To get the electric field you need the gradient of the charge density in the wire. Without the electric field the speed of the charged object would be constant and the magnetic force would be centripetal, changing from point to point as the B field and the velocity direction both change.  This motion (in three dimensions) might be approximated by a numeric simulation.